# iOS execute shell script from Activator

Tags: bash, ios5, jailbreak

I am using a jailbroken iOS device, and I want to add an action to Activator that executes a shell script stored in a known location. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether or not Activator can run scripts *directly*, but it certainly can run any **app** you install on your device, with whatever action (e.g. swipe, shake, button press) you like.  Just make a simple app that uses the `system()` function, or an `exec` function to invoke your script:

```obc
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int returnCode = system("/bin/myscript.sh arg1 arg2");
    return 0;
}
```

Then, setup Activator to run that app.

**Edit:**
That will cause a brief flash as the *app* starts, and then closes.  This also means that any other app that you're running will be closed (sent to the background). If you don't like that, Activator also lets you build a SBSettings *toggle*, and then run it on a user-defined action.    See [here for building a SBSettings toggle](http://thebigboss.org/guides-iphone-ipod-ipad/sbsettings-toggle-spec).  You would just implement the `setState` method this way:

```obc
void setState(BOOL Enabled) 
{
    int returnCode = system("/bin/myscript.sh arg1 arg2");
}
```

Comment: Sounds like that'd work great. Unfortunately, I don't have access to an OS X system to compile the binary. Are you willing to throw something together real quick that runs /var/mobile/script.sh? I know it's asking a favor of you, but I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Suchipi, yes, I can build it later today, and post a link to the binary file(s).

Comment: @Suchipi, do you have an app **Name** or icon that you want to use?  I can just make it with a blank white icon, but if you have an image file that you can post (as an **edit** to the question), or link to, then I'll use that.

Comment: @Suchipi, and I guess I also need to know if you want to install this with iTunes (which I think would require you giving me your device ID), or via Cydia (in which case I could put it on a test repo for you to download by adding a custom **Source** to Cydia).

Comment: You can use a blank white icon; I'll just customize it later. And you can either put it on Cydia or just archive the .app and I'll copy it in myself. I guess the app name can just be "Script". Thanks @Nate !

Comment: @Suchipi, ok I put the source and a [couple of pre-built downloads here](http://code.google.com/p/script-app-for-activator/downloads/list).  These will have to be copied over to (installed in) `/Applications/`, not in the usual `/var/mobile/Applications` folder for App Store apps.

Comment: Would it be possible to do this for ios 3.1.3?

Comment: @AshutoshJindal, I can't say for sure because I have no devices that old to test with. I think it *probably* would work. This makes it look like [Activator at one time worked with iPhoneOS 3.1.3](https://github.com/rpetrich/libactivator/issues/96). The question is whether you can today get Cydia and Activator to still work on 3.1.3, or whether something has broken.