# iOS app to run script

Tags: iphone, ios, bash, jailbreak

I would appreciate help in creating an iOS app to run a specified script at /var/mobile/script.sh. The script I have written opens a number of specified apps "all at once" on my jailbroken 6.1.2 iphone. Currently I run the script by starting MobileTerminal and manually running the script.sh file from the command line. I would like to be able to create an app that I could start via the Springboard which would run /var/mobile/script.sh directly.

I do not have a Mac and so I am unable to compile an app myself. I also do not have much experience of programming so I would appreciate any help on offer. I have seen an answer which is similar: [iOS execute shell script from Activator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223510/ios-execute-shell-script-from-activator)

The answer provided above is VERY close to what I am looking for. However I have two problems with the Script.app as it stands:

1) As the script I have written opens a number of other apps which takes around two minutes to complete, the Script.app is automatically killed by iOS after about 20 seconds. I'm not sure if a flag "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" needs to be set to allow Script.app to continue running so it can finish running my script? I have installed a package via Cydia called "Background Manager" - [which as I understand it makes all apps effectively think they are running in the foreground].

2) I have previously tested Script.app listed above on iOS 5 and the Script.app did run for around 20 seconds bringing the apps to the foreground as listed in my script.sh. On iOS 6.1.2 the Script.app runs certain commands in script.sh [e.g. killall commands] but when it comes to opening a specified app via the script it won't open any app [there is a blank black screen for 20 seconds and then the Script app closes without having opened any apps via the script.sh file]. However in iOS 6.1.2 if Script.app is started and immediately the home button is pressed to return you to the Springboard the Script.app will open apps via my script.sh for the first 20 seconds, so there appears to be a difference between the way the Script.app runs on iOS5 vs iOS6. I would like if Script.app could open apps via the script.sh without me having to immediately press the home button after Script.app starts on iOS 6

In my script file I use a command line package called "open" to specific which app to open via its CFBundleIdentifier: http://moreinfo.thebigboss.org/moreinfo/depiction.php?file=openData

Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks Nate - I have re-written the original question. I hope things are a bit clearer...

Comment: This is only for my personal use. A home screen icon would do the trick very nicely.

Comment: Yep I can SSH into the phone no problem. I use iFile to modify .plist files etc

Comment: Hi Nate. I appreciate the time you are spending on this. Check out "Background Manager":
http://moreinfo.thebigboss.org/moreinfo/depiction.php?file=backgroundmanagerDp
- I am able to run multiple apps as if they are all in the foreground. When this package has been installed it prevents an app from receiving an event from the iOS that another app is moving to the foreground - so the app never executes any "background code" when the other app starts up. In effect all apps think they are in the foreground.

Comment: Here is some more info of what "might" be happening in your Script.app:
"Your application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: methods should always be as lightweight as possible to reduce your app’s launch time. Apps are expected to launch and initialize themselves and start handling events in less than 5 seconds. If an app does not finish its launch cycle in a timely manner, the system kills it for being unresponsive. Thus, any tasks that might slow down your launch (such as accessing the network) should be executed asynchronously on a 2ndry thread."

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Comment: I do have SBSettings installed on my phone. A toggle which would load and unload a daemon that I could specify via a script would be particularly useful- however this would require root access [this was kind of a separate thing I would be interested in doing] but as it's all related I thought I would mention it here. I do know there is a "dock" feature in SBSettings that can be used to load individual apps.

Comment: Hi Nate. I'm not sure if this would be helpful. I noticed that one of the jailbroken packages that I have on my iphone called "Xpandr 2" has the ability to run scripts to completion. The manual for it is here: http://haunold.me/iphone/xpandr2/help.html. The command apparently that you enter is: {cmd:/var/mobile/script.sh}

Answer (score 3):

Here's a technique that should work for you.  It's not necessarily the way I'd solve it, but the solution is designed to work around you not having a Mac / Xcode.

One problem is that iOS expects normal "apps" to startup quickly, and begin responding to normal UI application events.  If you use [my original script launcher](https://github.com/n8r0n/script-app-for-activator), it does not actually create a `UIApplication`, but simply calls `system()` from the main program.  Assuming the call to `system()` completes quickly, there's no problem.  But, if *your* script takes 20 seconds to run, that's too long, and iOS will kill the app.

You *could* build a normal UI application, calling `UIApplicationMain()`, and starting your long-running script after the app finishes startup.  But really, you're not building an *app*.  You simply want to use a SpringBoard icon to kick off a script.  So, I don't think that solution makes a lot of sense.

What you probably want is a non-graphical *daemon* to run your long script for you.  For this, you could build a [Launch Daemon](http://chrisalvares.com/blog/7/creating-an-iphone-daemon-part-1/), and that might be how I solved the problem.  But, without Xcode, that's tough.  Another option is to take advantage of the privileged daemon that SBSettings has.  [You can use it to run your script](http://thebigboss.org/guides-iphone-ipod-ipad/sbsettings-toggle-spec).  Then, your "app" need only fire off a notification to tell SBSettings to run that script.  It can then exit, almost immediately.

Here is a [pre-built binary that invokes a script named com.mycompany.script](https://github.com/n8r0n/script-app-for-activator/releases) (get version 1.1).  Install this app on your iPhone (it can be installed normally, in the sandbox area).

Then, you'll need to put your script at (this **exact** path and filename):

```
/var/mobile/Library/SBSettings/Commands/com.mycompany.script
```

For example, its contents might be:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/open com.mycompany.AppOne
/usr/bin/open com.mycompany.AppTwo
/usr/bin/open com.mycompany.AppThree
exit 0;
```

where you're passing app bundle IDs to `open`.  You can put whatever you want inside it.  Make sure to login to your iPhone and set the right permissions on your script:

```sh
cd /var/mobile/Library/SBSettings/Commands/
chmod 755 com.mycompany.script 
chown mobile.mobile com.mycompany.script
```

and then reboot (re-springing might be enough to get SBSettings to recognize your new script).

---

*Note: for those who **are** coders, the main program of this app basically just contains this code:*

```objc
#include <notify.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   notify_post("com.mycompany.script");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nate. Had a bit of scary moment there for a second. I launched your app - and it did completely execute the script via the SBSettings daemon. Strangely it executed the script TWICE!! I left it running for 30 minutes and then I noticed the Springboard appeared to have frozen. After another minute or two the iPhone resprung. When the Springboard was displayed again, 99% of the app icons were missing :-(
I rebooted the device and fortunately all the apps are back again and the phone is working fine.

Comment: http://thebigboss.org/guides-iphone-ipod-ipad/sbsettings-toggle-spec  I'm not sure if this might be related to the following: Your toggle will run in springboard. This means if your toggle leaks memory, the system will be leaking memory. If your toggle crashes, the springboard will crash and you’ll get into safe mode

Comment: As a result I was wondering if the other methods you described: "build a normal UI application, calling UIApplicationMain(), and starting your long-running script after the app finishes startup" would be safer? At least that way just the app itself would crash rather than bringing down the entire iPhone. Would this also have the advantage that if I force quit the app half way during the script execution that it would stop executing the script? As the script takes 2 minute to run if I should change my mind it would be nice to have an easy way to stop the script without having to wait 4it2finish

Comment: If your script is crashing, I would look into that first.  Put some `echo` statements in between each app starting.  The other option is just another hack, and I'm not recommending it.  As to the script running twice, I don't know what to tell you.  I use this feature all the time, and my scripts never run twice.  Again, you should really try running that to ground.  You're right.  The technique I showed doesn't readily allow killing the script.  You didn't list that as a requirement.  It's important to be specific when posing your question.

Comment: The script I was running itself was fine. I now realize that one of the apps that it was opening VIA the script has a bug which is causing a problem in backboardd [which appears to deal with event handling in iOS]. Eventually this was causing the Springboard to become unresponsive. Everything is stable now that the app isn't being opened via the script.

Comment: Thank you for showing me the daemon that I can access through SBSettings. I have had a play with it and also read a few other posts you have written and I can see that the SBSettings daemon allows a script to run with ROOT ACCESS. This has allowed me to load a daemon via launchctl by tapping a springboard icon which is much easier for me than having to enter the commands manually via MobileTerminal. Which is brilliant - thanks :-)

Comment: I think the SBSettings daemon method is EXTREMELY good for running short running scripts - like loading/unloading a daemon. However for a very long running script i.e. 2 minutes in duration an app might be better - as it would allow me to kill the Script.app halfway during execution and might avoid problems if one of the apps that are being opened causes a memory leak - the Script.app could be killed by iOS without hopefully bringing down the entire Springboard.

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't explain things clearly in the beginning - as I come to understand the different methods of calling the script I now realize there are advantages/disadvantages of different methods.

Comment: You have asked me2b precise - so here goes: What would be great is 2have a toggle in SBSettings with Label "AutoLaunch" - which would have an OFF and and ON state. In the ON state it would run via /var/mobile/Library/SBSettings/Commands either of2 scripts e.g. com.sbsettings.enableAutoLaunch and com.sbsettings.disableAutoLaunch. I cud then put what ever scripting options I wanted in enableAutoLaunch/disableAutoLaunch. This would probably be a single line to load/unload a subsequent daemon via launchctl- which I could then use to start Launcher.app [see below] at a specified time/time internal.

Comment: As the script would be VERY short, SBSettings would be an ideal way of executing this script which would require ROOT ACCESS.

Comment: As a separate app e.g. Launcher.app it would be great to have the ability to run a specified script e.g. /var/mobile/script.sh. As THIS script does take a long time to run e.g. >2min - having this as an app would allow me to kill the script halfway during execution and may avoid problems if there was a subsequent memory leak which might otherwise bring down Springboard. You mention that this might be done by building a normal UI application, calling UIApplicationMain(), and starting the long-running script after the app finishes startup.

Comment: You have been very helpful. I have enjoyed learning how these things work and appreciate the time you've spent helping me out on this :-)